# Print string instead of error when list is empty

Tags: python, list, while-loop

```
def flips():
        print "Alright the workout of the day is a front-flip, back-flip and
                       side flip"                       
        flips_left = ['side flip', 'front flip', 'back flip']
        flip_choice = None

        while len(flips_left) > 0:
            flip_choice = raw_input("Do a flip ")
            if "side flip" in flip_choice:
                 print flip_lines['side_flip']
                 flips_left.remove('side flip')
                 print "Great! Now just do the rest: %s" % flips_left
             elif "front flip" in flip_choice:
                 print flip_lines['front_flip']
                 flips_left.remove('front flip')
                 print "Good stuff! This is what you have left: %s" %
                                 flips_left
             elif "back flip" in flip_choice:
                 print flip_lines['back_flip']
                 flips_left.remove('back flip')
             else:
              "That is not a type of flip! Try again!"

         print "Great! You completed the WOD!"
```

This question is actually a two-parter:

1. What I'm doing is telling the user to input 'side flip', 'back flip' or 'front flip'. When they do the input is removed from the list 'flips_left'. That works fine until say the user enters the same flip again, I want to return a message telling them they did that already,  and to try again.
2. For some reason I can't get the program to print the else statement when the user inputs something that isn't 'side flip' 'front flip' or 'back flip'. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should typically only ask one question per question, as you now have two answers each answering only one of your problems, which makes picking a correct answer difficult.

Comment: `"side flip" in flip_choice` will make `portside flippers` a valid choice. You want to use the equals sign: `flip_choice == "side flip"`.

Comment: @tcaswell Good point, I'll make sure to remember for the future.

Comment: @Blender Hahaha thanks for that, I'll make that change to my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement logic isn't checking what remains in `flips_left`

Your best bet would be to do something more generic such as:

```
if flip_choice in flips_left:
    print flip_lines[flip_choice]
    flips_left.remove(flip_choice)
else:
    print "Some error"
```

If you want to keep track of choices already made you could use a dictionary to keep track of which flips have already been performed.

```
flips_left = {'side flip':True, 'front flip':True, 'back flip':True}

...

if flip_choice in flips_left:
    if flips_left[flip_choice]:
        print flip_lines[flip_choice]
        flips_left[flip_choice] = False
    else:
        print "You have already done %s!" % flip_choice
else:
    print "That is not a valid flip"
```

Comment: Before I had: `if "side flip" in flip_choice and flips_left:` To try to check if the flips were still in the list, but nothing different happened so I removed it. Any idea why that didn't work? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks for the `dict` suggestion as well

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `print` keyword before your message:

```
else:
    print "That is not a type of flip! Try again!"
```

Comment: Damn it, that's apart of the reason why I didn't want to create a new question for that one. I knew it I was doing something incredibly  stupid, thanks.